# Finding trend of a time series data (Line or 1d data) using python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, time-series, line

I have a 1d time-series data or line. I want to know what is the trend of its slices. Picture:
[image]

some slices are equal, some are uptrend and some slices are downtrend. In the picture the green marker shows uptrend and red are showing downtrend.

I want to have a list or array that show each index is in which slice.
For example, I want something like this:
[equal, equal, ..., up, up, ..., down, down]
each item is just a tag that shows the direction of its slice. For example, if the second item in the list is 'up', this means that the instance is placed in the slice which is uptrend.

I have tried many ways best of them was scipy's argrelextrema.

I have used arglextrema for finding local maxima and minima then comparing them by order of appearance in the index.

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
d = data['tenkan_sen'].fillna(1)
h1 = d.append(pd.Series([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]), ignore_index=True)
g = argrelextrema(h1.values, np.greater)[0]
l = argrelextrema(h1.values, np.less)[0]
e = argrelextrema(h1.values, np.equal)[0]

extermas = dict()
extermas[0] = 'start'
for item in g:
    extermas[item] = 'greater'
for item in l:
    extermas[item] = 'less'
extermas = dict(sorted(extermas.items()))
idx_extermas = list(extermas.keys())

status = []

for item in range(len(idx_extermas)-1):
    if extermas[idx_extermas[item+1]] == 'less':
        stat = 'down'
    if extermas[idx_extermas[item+1]] == 'greater':
        stat = 'up'
    for _ in range(idx_extermas[item], idx_extermas[item+1]):
        #print(_)
        status.append(stat)
        
#print(len(status))
for item in e:
    #print(item)
    status[item] = 'equal'
```

This method cannot find the direction of the ending slice of the line. to solve this problem, I have added five points manually at the end of the line, but it did not work.
I have searched a lot I could not find a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you want to smooth out your data, run

```
data=np.convolve(data,[1/4,2/4,1/4],"valid")
```

This will remove noise, but also blur your data and shrink it slightly as it does so.
Then run

```
data=np.convolve(data,[1,-1],"valid")
gap=0.1
direction=(data>gap).astype(int)-(data<-gap).astype(int)
```

This gives you an array that is 1 when the data was sloping upwards by at least gap, and -1 when sloping downwards. (In general being exactly constant is rare in most data sets, you only want to pick up the steep slopes.)
Adjust gap until you are only picking out the steepness you want.

Comment: what is the gap? does its value matter? Does the convolve operation change the list's length? I tested it, it seems the direction list is 3, 4 items less than main list.

Comment: Gap measures how steep the data has to be before it is counted as sloping up, not as practically flat.

Comment: The first convolve makes each value into a weighted average of it and the values on the left and right. But there is nothing left of the leftmost, or right of the rightmost, so these values are removed. Likewise, the second convolution looks at the difference between successive values, and so the output is one shorter than the input. The second convolve is equivalent to "data=data[1:]-data[:-1]"

Comment: So this means that it does not work for the last sample of data, right? But, the last sample is very important to me. Is it possible to find direction of the last sample?

Comment: If you skip the first convolve, the last value in the array will be comparing the second last sample to the last one.